# C Compiler cannot create executables, OpenSolaris Erlang/OTP ./configure error

Tags: c++, c, gcc, erlang, solaris

was running the `./configure` script for OTP14B03 on OpenSolaris and got the following output

```
Ignoring the --cache-file argument since it can cause the system to be erroneously configured
Disabling caching
checking build system type... i386-pc-solaris2.11
checking host system type... i386-pc-solaris2.11
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
```

I have gcc4 installed, in the $PATH, installed libgcc installed, but still getting this error. searching the web got me to try adding `/usr/ccs/bin` in order to locate the `ld.so` file (probably got to do with C++ Compiler or linker). Could some one help me out

EDIT:
Config/log file contains this:

```
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:2041: $? = 0
configure:2043: gcc -v &5
Reading specs from /usr/local/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/3.4.6/specs
Configured with: ../configure --with-as=/usr/ccs/bin/as --with-ld=/usr/ccs/bin/ld --enable-shared --enable-languages=c,c++,f77
Thread model: posix
gcc version 3.4.6
configure:2046: $? = 0
configure:2048: gcc -V &5
gcc: `-V' option must have argument
configure:2051: $? = 1
configure:2074: checking for C compiler default output file name
configure:2077: gcc    conftest.c  >&5
ld: fatal: file values-Xa.o: open failed: No such file or directory
ld: fatal: file processing errors. No output written to a.out
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:2080: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h.  */
| 
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:2118: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
```

Comment: Please post the relevant part of `config.log`, no way to tell what the problem is without that.

Comment: done that, could you up vote my question please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your linker cannot find the `values-Xa.o` object file.

According to [this FAQ](http://www.sunfreeware.com/faq.html#q5), it either means your system is missing a package required by the compiler, or that the required packages are installed but your default library path does not reflect it.

As a quick check, you can try adding `/usr/ccs/lib` to the library path:

```
./configure LDFLAGS="-L/usr/ccs/lib"
```

Comment: `solaris2.11` means either Solaris 11 Express or an OpenSolaris distro.   `pkg search values-Xa.o` should show the name of the package to install.   Unfortunately, S11 Express put it in the confusingly named `developer/library/lint` package which people not using lint often think they don't need to install.